# Most performant way to invert an array?

Tags: ruby

If I have an array like

```
ary = [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

What is the most performant way to get a list of how many indexes were in the array?

```
inverted = [2,2,2,6,6,8,10,11]
```

This is what I've come up with, but it seems like there is a more efficient way:

```
a = []
ary.each_with_index{|v,i| a << Array.new(v, i) if v != 0}
a.flatten
 => [2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 8, 10, 11]
```

Comment: I would recommend rewriting your question, and make it clearer what you are trying to do. First of all, 'inverting' isn't the best way to describe what you are doing. What you are trying to do is create some sort of inverted index. But it seems that this is a problem that is solved with just one pass, and that is what you are doing. If you list isn't large, I'd stick with that.

Comment: IMHO: When faced with any kind of algorithm, you should first try functional solutions (stateless, no in-place updates), even if they are slightly slower. Is this the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: I'm not sure how I wasn't clear given I gave an example, and also coded what i was looking for.  Clearly two people thought I gave enough information.

Comment: It only made sense to me when I ran the code without the flatten call.  Could you explain what value there is to this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless profiling proves this to be a bottleneck, the cleaner is a functional approach:

```
>> ary.each_with_index.map { |x, idx| [idx]*x }.flatten(1)
=> [2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 8, 10, 11]
```

If you use Ruby 1.9, I'd recommend this (thanks to sawa for pointing out `Enumerable#flat_map`):

```
>> ary.flat_map.with_index { |x, idx| [idx]*x }
=> [2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 8, 10, 11]
```

[edit: removed examples using `inject` and `each_with_object`, it's unlikely they are faster than `flat_map` + `with_index`]

Comment: You can leave out the **if x>0** and the **compact**, since [1]*0 == [] and the empty arrays disappear while flattened.

Comment: I have reacently learned that there is `Enumerable#flat_map` in ruby 1.9. That will make it even shorter, and probably faster.

Comment: I actually added a version using `flat_map` to your answer.

Comment: @sawa: oh, we have a concatMap in Ruby 1.9, good to know! (I am still tied to Ruby 1.8.7). Now the solution is really compact and beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Array#push instead of Array#<< to speed this up a little.

```
ary.each_with_index{|v,i| a.push(*Array.new(v, i)) if v != 0}
```

Some quick benchmarking shows me that this is about 30% faster than using `<<`.

```
> ary = [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0] 
# => [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
> quick_bench(10**5) do
> a = []
> ary.each_with_index{|v,i| a << Array.new(v, i) if v != 0}
> a.flatten
> end
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   1.200000   0.020000   1.220000 (  1.209861)
--------------------------- total: 1.220000sec

       user     system      total        real
   1.150000   0.000000   1.150000 (  1.147103)
# => nil
> quick_bench(10**5) do
> a = []
> ary.each_with_index{|v,i| a.push(*Array.new(v, i)) if v != 0}
> end
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.870000   0.000000   0.870000 (  0.865190)
--------------------------- total: 0.870000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.860000   0.000000   0.860000 (  0.858628)
# => nil
> a = []
# => []
> ary.each_with_index{|v,i| a.push(*Array.new(v, i)) if v != 0}
# => [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
> a
# => [2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 8, 10, 11]
>
```